# Removing parentnode but not childnodes XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml

I'm in a situation where i need to get rid of my parentnode, but not my childnodes.

Here is how it loooks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:MisMessage>
  <mislife>
    <party/>
    <datetime>2018-06-04T09:35:33</datetime>
    <insurance">
      <number>123</number>
      <amount>3</amount>
      <indicator></indicator>
      <text>asd</text>
    </insurance>
  </mislife>
  <ns0:Message/>
</ns0:MisMessage>
```

And here is how i want it to look after i'm done.

```
 <mislife>
   <party/>
   <datetime>2018-06-04T09:35:33</datetime>
   <insurance">
     <number>123</number>
     <amount>3</amount>
     <indicator></indicator>
     <text>asd</text>
   </insurance>
 </mislife>
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I have tried and tried and tried. I have been looking all over the internet and i can't find out how to do it. The thing i want to remove will always be named ns0: in the beggning. Can i do it by removeing with substrings? THANKS!

I solved it like below, i converted the XMLDocument to XDocument and then used the descendants. Just like @bommelding showed in his example. Thank you all!

```
var xDocument = ToXDocument(xmlDocument);
if (xDocument != null)
{
    var mislife = xDocument.Descendants("mislife").FirstOrDefault();
    if (mislife != null)
    {
        return mislife;
    }
}

public static XDocument ToXDocument(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
    {
        nodeReader.MoveToContent();
        return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read all `mslife` elements and write them to a new xml document. Show what you've tried.

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML (XDocument, XElement etc) rather than XmlDocument/XmlElement? That generally makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: It would also be useful if you could show what you've tried, and what the result was.

Comment: @Andrea no, i only need to get rid of the parentnode. Not the namespaces.

Comment: @mobbelding better now?

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes i am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XElement data = doc
      .Descendants("mislife")  // find your target
      .Single();               // be brave, there should be exactly 1
data.Save(otherFileName);      // saves with document <? ... ?>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What more would you like to see?  The answer is clear and complete, adding blah blah would only increase the time-to-read.

Comment: @bommelding I did though, need to add .FirstOrDefault to the xDocument.Descendants("mislife") for it to be able to work.

Comment: Descendant != Descendants, but that was a typo on my side. I will edit.

Comment: You should explain what you giving solution to OP

Comment: @N.Jadhav - I have explained all i can or care for. Feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way with Linq (remember to add using System.Xml.Linq;):

```
string testxml = @"
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(testxml).Descendants().First().Document;
```

doc will be your xml without the root element

XDocument can load from files with

```
XDocument.Load("path");
```

or read XML like I did with

```
Xml.Parse("<xml....>");
```

and have also other options.

Result is:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```